# Ionic, how to use cordova plugin, not ng-cordova / typescript

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic v.1, Angular 1.4 and typescript.

And I need to use a plugin which is not ng-cordova plugin.

I installed this plugin,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions@0.10.0
```

And now I have no idea how to use this in my service.

```
export class TestService implements ITestService {
    constructor(private $cordovaInAppBrowser: ngCordova.IInAppBrowserService,
        private $cordovaFileTransfer: ngCordova.IFileTransferService,
        private $cordovaFileOpener2: any,
        private $ionicLoading: ionic.loading.IonicLoadingService,
        private $window: angular.IWindowService) {
    }
```

How can I inject the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to inject it. You simply have to use it like it is written in the doc. The variables will be declared globally.
Also, it will be attached to $window.
So, for example, if you need to do :

`var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
permissions.hasPermission(permission, successCallback, errorCallback);`

You can also do :

`var permissions = $window.cordova.plugins.permissions;
permissions.hasPermission(permission, successCallback, errorCallback);`